# Let $f\colon A\to A$; prove that if $f\circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$ then $f$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f\colon A\to A$; prove that if $f\circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$ then $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: Injectivity: Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$, what can you say about $f(f(x))$ and $f(f(y))$.
Surjectivity: Given $a\in A$, there exists $b\in A$ such that $f(b)=a$ since, $f(f(a))=id(a)=a$ so b=?

Comment: To Prove Injectivity I would say that if

Comment: To Prove Injectivity could I say that since fof is the identity function then f(f(x)) = f(x) = x and f(f(y)) = f(y) = y. then x =y so its injective.  

To prove Surjectivity could I say that Given b∈A, there exists a∈A such that f(a)=b since, f(f(a))=id(a)=a so b=a?         

Also I was wondering If I could just say that since fof is an identity function it must be a composition of bijections therefore f is a bijection?

Comment: @Bradley: The injectivity part is right. For surjectivity, "proving" $b=a$ would mean that $f$ is identity which it need not be. Since, $f(f(a))=a$ what element maps to $a$ under $f$?

Comment: It seems like both a and f(a) map to a under f? My goal is to show b = f(a) correct?

Comment: So since f(f(a)) = a and f(b) = a then b = f(a)?

Comment: @Bradley: Your last comment is right. Your second last comment is not necessarily true. $a$ may not map to $a$, but $f(a)$ does.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for the **Green and Brown Fact**, namely Theorem 8 on page 14 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/3200relationsfunctions.pdf).  (The name comes from the colors of the chalk I used to draw a box around it that day in class.)  If you have a composition of functions $g \circ f$, this tells you that if the composite function is injective, $f$ is injective, and if the composite function is surjective, $g$ is surjective.

The question asked by the OP fits so nicely into this framework that I feel embarrassed not to have discussed it either time I taught the course.  Next time I will.

Ooh, another good exercise: what if $f \circ f \circ f = \operatorname{Id}_A$, and so forth.