# If $f \circ f$ is bijective for $f: A \to A$, then is $f$ bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $f: A \to A$. If $f \circ f$ is a bijection, then $f$ is bijective.

My proof looked like this:

---

We know that $|A| = |A|$. Since this is the case, there exists a bijection $f: A \to A$ which has us conclude that $f$ is bijective.

---

Is this sufficient to prove the statement? Or must I separately prove surjectivity and injectivity for $f$ using $f \circ f$?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but almost: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13135/let-f-colon-a-to-a-prove-that-if-f-circ-f-mathrmid-a-then-f-is-a-bij

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because $f \circ f$ can be any bijection. Thanks for showing me the similar question though.

Comment: If I thought it was a duplicate, I would have closed the question. It's *almost* a duplicate, since the argument is quite similar.

Comment: Oh, right. That would make sense then. :P

Comment: There exists a bijection $A\to A$, but not necessarly $f$!!

Comment: Dear @Kookie, Your reasoning does not make sense; $f$ is not a function whose existence you can deduce; any set $A$ admits the bijection $\mathrm{id}_A:A\to A$. You are given $f$ and the hypothesis that $f\circ f$ is bijective. So, yes, you need to use this assumption to prove that $f$ is injective and surjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asked to prove a property of a particular function $f$. Saying that there exists a bijection From $A$ onto $A$ proves nothing.

Suppose $f\circ f$ is  a bijection. The $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $f(f(x))=f(f(y))$ which implies $x=y$. So $f$ is injective. I will let you show that $f$ is surjective also.

Comment: Can I prove surjectivity by saying that since $f \circ f$ is surjective, $\forall x \in A, \exists y \in A$ such that $f \circ f(x) = y$, then let $k = f(x) \in A$ and say $\forall k \in A, \exists y \in A$ such that $f(k) = y$ and conclude that $f$ is surjective?

Comment: @Kookie Yoo wrote $\forall x \in A \exists y \in A$ instead of  $\forall y \in A \exists x \in A$

Comment: It's not a typo. Is it really the other way around?

Comment: If you say for each $x$ there exists $y$ such that $f(x)=y$ you are only saying that $f$ is a well defined function. To show that it is surjective you have to show that for each $y$ there exists $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $fo g$ is bijection $\implies g$ is one-one and $f$ is onto.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof comes down to using the same letter $f$ for two different things. You are, first of all, given an $f: A \longrightarrow A$. You furthermore write that there exists a bijection $A \longrightarrow A$. You shouldn't call this map $f$, as there's no reason to believe that it's the same as the map you're originally. Indeed, your argument would imply that all maps $A \longrightarrow A$ are bijections, which is nonsense if $|A| \geq 2$.

Back to the proof itself, we do indeed have to show that $f$ is injective and surjective. We certainly have $im(f \circ f) = A$. Furthermore, $im(f \circ f) = f[f[A]]$. Hence, $im(f) \supseteq f[f[A]] = A$, so $f$ is onto. For injectivity, suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. By surjectivity, let $f(a) = x$, $f(b) = y$. Then $f(f(a)) = f(x) = f(y) = f(f(b))$, so $a = b$. Thus, $x = f(a) = f(b) = y$.