# Given that  ◦  is a bijection, prove that  itself must be a bijection

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition, elementary-functions

Does this proof work to show that  is a bijection if the composite  ◦  is a bijection? We are given that  is a function from A → A.

**Injective**:
Let x, y ∈ A. Assume (x) = (y).

By the composite function being a bijection, if ((x)) = ((y)), x = y. Then each z = ((x)) = ((y)) ∈ A has a y = (x) = (y) ∈ A, which has x = y ∈ A. Thus, when (x) = (y), x = y.

**Surjective**:
Let x, y ∈ A. Since the composite function is a bijection, each z = ((x)) ∈ A has a corresponding x ∈ A such that ((x)) = z. Then each z = ((x)) also has a y ∈ A = (x) ∈ A for which y = (x). Thus for the function , each y ∈ A has an x such that y = (x), and  is a mapping onto A.

Since  is both injective and surjective, it is a bijection.
Does this proof make sense?

Comment: Compare it with the standard proof.

Comment: @DonThousand: Your linked question says "I was able to prove this without difficulty", but doesn't give the proof. So no, it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry should I be comparing it with the standard proof for "a composite of bijections is a bijection"?

Comment: It is correct, but too complicated. Injective: If $f(x) = f(y)$, then $f^2(x) = f^2(y)$ and $x = (f^2)^{-1}(f^2(x)) = (f^2)^{-1}(f^2(y)) = y$. Surjective: Let $z \in A$ and $x = f((f^2)^{-1}(z))$. Then $f(x) = z$.

Comment: A direct duplicate is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597175/if-f-circ-f-is-bijective-for-f-a-to-a-then-is-f-bijective). There are several more, and you can compare. The answers there are really very similar to all what we have seen here.

Comment: Your proof smells correct, although I haven't gone over it with a fine-toothed comb.